# why should we not use domain objects in views?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am just confused why it is bad practice to use domain objects in views?  I am told it can leave to model binding attacks but I'm not exactly sure what this is or how it can be done.  I also don't quite understand how copying the properties to a viewmodel will solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using viewmodels beside other benefits (e.g separating your view related logic from your domain logic) will prevent from [mass-assigment](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/11/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your domain objects often contain properties that define flags like `isAdmin, isDeleted, isAuthorized` or any other security or sensitive info that you may not want the final user to mess with, even if you only show it in a readonly state you are giving away the property name in the view/html, giving some 'smart users' the chance to play with your POST actions, and if you didn't take the right precautions this may lead to security holes.

If you use a ViewModel you are forced to do a remap from the `ViewModel <-> Model` (Domain objects), in this remapping you can make sure that the assignments are just the ones you want from any particular user something like:

```
if(CurrentUser.IsAdmin)
{
   //Assign just if the current user is admin
   Model.IsDeleted = ViewModel.Delete;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You domain objects can contain sensitive information, like `IsAuthenticated`, `UserRoles`, etc. that should not be allowed to affect directly from client code.

If your domain objects does not contain anything else but the properties to show on screen, then you might not need a domain model in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Well. User can modify any field in your domain object. It's how the model binding in ASP MVC works. All they need to do is to modify the form before posting it. For example, you can use Chrome/Firefox developer tools.

I've blogged about it: http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/07/three-reasons-to-why-you-should-use-view-models/

Answer (score 1):

Using domain models in view is not always bad.
Model Binding attacks is providing values for properties are not intended for editing.
To prevent model binding attacks mark your action parameters with [BindAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) and specify Exclude or Include (better) with list of properties allowed to be bound.

Comment: +1 for BindAttribute. Combine it with a constructor that sets the sensitive fields to good default values and you are safe.